# Showing a family in a separable Hilbert space is a basis.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{e_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis for separable Hilbert space $H$. Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal set such that

$$\sum_n \vert \vert e_n - f_n \vert \vert<1.$$

Prove $\{f_n\}$ is a basis for $H$.

My Thoughts,

By Besssels inequality, one has

$$\sum_n \vert \langle f_n,e_n \rangle \vert \leq \vert \vert f_n \vert \vert^2.$$

where the RHS is just $1$? since the $f_n$ form an orthonormal set. This was the only exercise that gave me trouble today..Wait by Parsevals I get equality. So I need to show closure of  $\text{span}\{f_1,f_2,...\}$ is all of $H$? i.e., the span of the $f_n$ is dense in $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume to the contrary that $\{f_n\}$ is not a basis, then there exists a unit vector $h$ such that $\langle h, f_n \rangle = 0$ for all $n$. We have,

$$\begin{split}
1 &= (\sum_n |\langle h, e_n \rangle|^2)^{1/2}\\
&\leq (\sum_n (|\langle h, f_n \rangle| + \|h\|\|e_n - f_n\|)^2)^{1/2}\\
&= (\sum_n \|e_n - f_n\|^2)^{1/2}\\
&\leq \sum_n \|e_n - f_n\|\\
&< 1
\end{split}$$

A contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Define the linear map $$
T:H\to H,T(e_i)=f_i
$$
The inequality tells you that $\vert \vert T-I \vert \vert <1$, in particular $T=I-(I-T)$ is invertible, hence $(f_i)$ is a basis and in fact an orthonormal basis.To see that:$\vert \vert T-I \vert \vert <1$, pick an element $x=(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of the unit sphere of $H$ expanded in the basis $(e_n)_{n\geq 1}$ , then:
$$
\vert\vert (T-I)x \vert \vert \leq \sum_{n\geq 1} \vert x_n\vert \vert \vert e_n-f_n \vert\vert  \leq \vert \vert x\vert \vert  \sqrt{\sum_{n\geq 1}  \vert \vert e_n-f_n \vert\vert ^{2} } \leq \sum_{n\geq 1}  \vert \vert e_n-f_n \vert\vert <1
$$